# iOS Game that Runs Continuously in Background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, coronasdk

I'm trying to understand the most logical way of creating an iOS game that runs continuously in the background.

For example.. you have tower and enemy waves. The game has endless enemy waves even when the game exits. When you open the game again, it will retrieve the data that occurred when the app was closed.

I assume a database on a server would be the best solution. The values continuously increment on the server. The game connects to the server and retrieves the specific user's updated game data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A server / database will only be helpful if you would like to present your information to multiple users, for a high score board for example.

In your case it seems that the easiest way to do it would be to store locally the time when the app was exited, and when you open the game again, you compare the current time to time stored before, and you calculate the impacts of all waves occuring between time now - time before.

Example: let's say you have 10 enemy monsters per minute, i exit the game i store the time (12:35), i open the game again at 12:45, 10 minutes difference * 10 enemy monsters have attacked my towers... From there you calculate the impact of 100 enemy monsters on your towers :)

Makes sense ?
And all without any complicated client / server programming.

Cheers

Comment: That makes sense. However, is this feasible on an iOS device? And doesn't this solution leave the game open to "cheating" such as if a user alters his or her machine time?

Comment: Well there are two matters here: 

#1 A motivated hacker will always find a way to hack your game. And actually, making the client server programming right without any exploits might be a lot more complicated and prone to security issues.

#2 It's quite easy to encrypt your local data to make the hacker's life complicated :)

Comment: And yep the example i gave is feasible on an iOS device :) You just have to request the system time :)

Comment: @user2913669 It's a fairly common technique.  Any iOS game that work offline has to do this because you aren't allowed to stay running in the background.

Comment: thanks for the responses. so you're both saying accessing the time locally is the best solution? Could you elaborate on how to prevent users from say simply changing their system time?

Comment: I see 2 protections you can add against that:
First one would be to check that the time difference between your local stored time and the current time when restoring isn't too big. If the number is over a certain limit (say, more than 7 days), display an error message or anything you want and overwrite the time stored with the current time without earning anything. That will prevent users from changing system time to 10 years in the future :) Or you could even allow users to get credits for offline time only up to one day for example... Then problem is almost entirely solved.

Comment: Second one i can see is, IF the device is online, to call a web time api to check against the current time, but same issue as before, the device needs to be connected and the call is subject to a man in the middle attack anyway...
There is no way to really prevent it if the hacker is really really motivated, you can only make his job harder.

Comment: Isn't there a way to obtain the device's uptime, ie time since it was first booted or connected to iTunes? I remember something like that exists, resetting that is more intricate than just changing the clock in the Settings app.